# How to add bookmark that connects to local server?

Tags: nautilus

Usually I start my terminal and login to some server with the following line:

```
ssh -X myuser@myserver.de
```

Now I would like to add a bookmark so that I can login while brousing through the folders with my mouse.

When I add network bookmark I can only edit the location, the following does not work

```
network:///myuser@myserver.de
```

I remember that I was able to add such a bookmark on a different computer. There I could add something like the username, host, port etc.

I use ubuntu 12.04. Please let me know how to add the bookmark.

Comment: If you able to ssh in, you could try entering `sftp:////myuser@myserver.de` instead of `network://` - also I'm not sure which bookmarks you refer to, but have you tried `Ctrl+D`?

Comment: @drgrog yes I refere to the Ctrl+D bookmark. If I try to enter your suggestions I get an error message, telling me no hostname specified. Thank you for your suggestet link but I have no problem with adding afolder bookmark, my problem is that I cant add my simple connection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:
 Open the file browser (Nautilus) go to File -> Connect to Server

Now enter in the field **Server Address**

```
ssh://myuser@myserver.de
```

A folder to this server will appear in Nautilus. Now just right-click on it and save it as a bookmark

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean with "bookmark"? I remember that once in gnome terminal you can add some bookmarks (and now that feature doesn't exist no more, AFAIK) but I don't remember that it was possible export such bookmarks from a computer to another one.

If you're looking for something exportable, maybe you can drop down a little script doing something like

```
gnome-terminal -e "ssh -X [and whatever you want] user@hostname.domain"
```

Cheers,

Silvia

Comment: I mean the Bookmarks that you add with Ctrl+D. I mean a Network Bookmark. I just want to browse to files that are on a other computer in my network. However this network does not appear at "Browse Network" so I have to add the host manual.